# Smack Pack and Pitching Time

Tags: yeast, smack-pack, fermentation

So I completed my first batch of homebrew this morning, but I forgot one potentially (okay, not potentially, definitely) important aspect of the whole process: the yeast. I didn't forget it, per se, but I forgot that I was supposed to smack the smack pack three hours in advance (per the instructions on the Wyeast Activator package, it says three hours in advance or pitch immediately). Being a beer wunderkind, I split the difference and smacked it 90 minutes before pitch time. It had expanded some before I pitched it, but it wasn't quite full. Should I be concerned? More importantly, if I don't see fermentation activity in the next 24-36 hours, can I just put in more yeast (properly prepared this time)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Relax & have a homebrew.  The pouch in the smack pack contains a little food and nutrients which gets the yeast going.  You pitched the yeast (and pouch contents) into a sea of food and nutrients.  Your fermentation will lag just a little but should take off.

Comment: That's all the reassurance I need. Thanks for that!

Comment: My airlock is bubbling away merrily this morning. Unfounded worry on my part, I guess. Still, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Good news. (-: Keep it up

Answer (score 3):

Smacking the pack only gives you a way to assess the viability of the yeast.  It does not "activate" the yeast nor increase the cell count.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Yeah, straight from Greg Doss at Wyeast.