# Why is it bad to pitch too much yeast?

Tags: yeast, fermentation, ingredients, techniques

What are the effects of over-pitching?  Where is the line for, say, a 1.050 beer?

There is also a question for to [under-pitching](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/why-is-it-bad-to-pitch-too-little-yeast).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeast produce different flavors during the various stages of their lifecycle.  Overpitching shortens or skips their "growth" phase (maybe a better name is "division" or "budding").  The bulk of a beer's esters are produced during this initial stage, so missing out on a fully-developed life cycle robs an ale of this often desirable quality.

A by-product of yeast metabolism is acetaldehyde, characterized by green apple flavor.  During a full fermentation yeast will scrub much of this undesirable compound out of the beer.  Overpitching could result in a noticeable amount of acetaldehyde left over.

To avoid the problem, use Jamil's [pitching rate calculator](http://www.mrmalty.com/calc/calc.html) and stay within 15-20% of the recommended rate.